# How can I get request parameters from REST style URL in thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf

In the thymeleaf documentation there's only option to get request parameters from urls which looks like,

```
https://example.com/getUser?id=10
```

I can use `${param.id[0]}` to access the user id in thymeleaf whereas if I have a REST-style url like this,

```
https://example.com/user/10
```

How can I access the user id(10) in the page using thymeleaf with the above URL? Of course I can set a model attribute to access the id of user in the page. But just wondering if there any better way to do this in thymeleaf in order to minimize the code?

Answer (score 2):

Well there is no direct helper AFAIK but your best shot is something like this:

```
${#strings.listSplit(#httpServletRequest.requestURI,'/')[1]}
```

note that `1` which is the list index of splitted url varies according to your url structure.

Note that `#httpServletRequest.requestURI` gives you `user/10` and `listSplit` gives you `[user, 10]`